# Sharing Notes on Catalina

Tags: icloud, notes.app, catalina, ios

I have been using shared notes on my Mac and iOS devices for years now. Everything worked fine until iOS 13 / Catalina.

Now when I try to create a shared note it tells me either the server could not be reached or [image]

When I go to iCloud.com I can create shared notes. Old shared notes, that I created before updating, also still work.

I tried logging out of iCloud and logging back in again, but that did not work. Are others having this problem too?

Does anyone know how I can solve this, or is this just something I have to hope get's solved in a coming update?

Thanks
- Joseph

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps if the issue occurred immediately after upgrading

1. Open the **Terminal** app, which is in the **Utilities** folder of your Applications folder.
2. Type this command in **Terminal**:

   */System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed*
3. Press Return and wait for the Terminal prompt—which ends in $—to reappear. It may take a few minutes.
4. Quit Terminal.

And later go to **Apple menu** > **System Preferences**, click **Extensions**, and make sure that the Markup and sharing features are turned on in the Actions and Share Menu sections too after running the above command.

Comment: Hi, tried this - no change... Still get the message "Invitation could not be sent"